# Is the measure evaluation map measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

I have a separable metric space $X$ from which I form the space of Borel probability measures on it, $\Delta(X)$. This last set is metrized by the topology of weak convergence (or by the Prokhorov metric on measures). Finally, I have a borel probability measure on $\Delta(X)$, denoted by $\pi$.

I would like to know, under what conditions (on $X$ alone preferably, but maybe also on $\pi$) is the evaluation map $F:B(X)\times \Delta(X)\to[0,1]$ given by $F(A,\mu):=\mu(A)$ is jointly measurable, where $B(Y)$ is the collection of Borel-measurable subsets of $Y$. It would be enough for me to have measurability of the sections $F_{A}:\Delta(X)\to[0,1]$, given by $F_{A}(\mu):=F(A,\mu)$.

Thanks!
Alejandro

Comment: I guess both occurrences of $B(\Delta(X))$ should be $\Delta(X)$?

Comment: Thanks for that, I just corrected it.

Comment: I believe I have an answer, and it is that $X$ is Polish.

Comment: What is your $\sigma$-algebra on $B(X)$? Or what exactly do you mean by jointly measurable?

Comment: Good point!! I don't know exactly what I mean. What I want is for $F_{A}$ to be measurable for every Borel set $A$. This holds if $X$ is Polish - with $\Delta(X)$ endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra corresponding to the topology of weak convergence.