# Is the "call" or "evaluation" function measurable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request, measurable-functions

The call function is defined as

$$
\text{call}: \begin{cases}
    (\mathbb{R}^{I}\times I) \to \mathbb{R} \\
    (f,x) \mapsto f(x)
\end{cases}
$$

is "$\text{call}$" a measurable function? In other words: for a random field $Z:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and a random location $X\in\mathbb{R}^n$, is $Z(X)$ a random variable?

To address a comment: This is not simply a question of chaining measurable functions, as both $Z$ and $X$ depend on $\omega$. I.e we really have
$Z(\omega):\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$, so $\omega\mapsto Z(\omega)(X(\omega))=\text{call}(Z(\omega), X(\omega))$ needs to be measurable.

I would guess this should be correct tough. At least for continuous random fields. But I am not sure what to search for. In a programming context "call" would be appropriate (cf. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). I am mostly looking for a reference to cite.

Comment: There are coninuity theorems for the evaluation map (what you call "call") if we restrict the function space I guess. Maybe you find something using the term "evaluation map"

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324130/is-the-measure-evaluation-map-measurable

Comment: Is your question if we are given two measurable functions $$X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n, Z: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ that the composition $Z(X): \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable too?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven No. The evaluation is not an obvious composition of two measurable functions (proving each component is measurable is likely as hard as showing the evaluation is measurable anyway!). $I=[0,1]$ here, not an integer $n$

Comment: @SeverinSchraven no. It is, whether $h$ with $h(Z,x)=Z(x)$ is measurable.

Comment: @FShrike, actually I had $I=\mathbb{R}^n$ in mind. Since $Z:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is from the set $\mathbb{R}^I$ then. I hope you do not need $I$ to be compact

Comment: @FelixB. Oh, $I=[0,1]$ is standard notation. But locally compact Hausdorff (in the sense described in my post) holds for $\Bbb R^n$ and is sufficient.

Comment: @FelixB. I am not making that claim, I am asking. Sometimes people want to know things different from what they write.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: previously this presented a dead end, but with @FShrike's answer this does not make any sense anymore. Instead I want to elaborate on  @FShrike's answer. Partly to explain it to myself.

## The Continuity Approach

The main idea is: A common **sufficient** criterion for measurability with regard to the **Borel** sigma algebra is continuity. So if we get continuity, we get Borel measurability for free. This opens three questions:

1. Is our evaluation/call function actually continuous?
2. Is the Borel sigma algebra what we want?

   - is the sigma algebra we want a Borel sigma algebra at all?
   - have we generated the Borel sigma algebra from the correct topology?
3. If the evaluation/call function is not continuous, can it still be measurable?

### 1 Is the evaluation function continuous?

This is the main concern of @FShrike's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4587832/445105). The first question is of course, what topology can we give $\mathbb{R}^I$?

It appears there is the concept of an [Exponential Topology](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Exponential_topology), which exists for very general $I$ ([locally compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space) [Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space) is sufficient). And the evaluation function is always continuous with regard to this topology.

### 2 Is the Borel Sigma algebra what we want?

@FShrike also addresses the question whether we have the correct topology somewhat. It appears that

the [exponential topology](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Exponential_topology) is identical to the [compact-open  topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology) if and only if the evaluation function is continuous with regard to the compact open topology.

The compact-open topology is only defined on the set of continuous functions $C(I)$ though. But according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology), the evaluation function is continuous with regards to the compact-open topology. This implies that the two topologies *do* coincide, which makes the exponential topology a reasonable extension for non-continuous functions.

#### What sigma algebra do we want?

Let us now start from the probability side: What do we want? Due to Kolmogorov's extension theorem, probabilists like to work with the sigma algebra $\mathcal{A}$ generated by finite cylinder sets.

What does that mean?

For a finite Subset $J=\{t_1,\dots,t_n\}\subset I$ we define the finite dimensional projection

$$
\pi_J(f):= (f(t_1),\dots,f(t_n))
$$

A cylinder is of the form $\pi_J^{-1}(A_1\times\dots\times A_n)$, because for any value $t\not\in J$ the functions in this set can take any value. So informally we have

$$
\pi_J^{-1}(A_1\times\dots\times A_n) 
= A_1\times\dots\times A_n \times \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times...
\subset \mathbb{R}^I
$$

So the sigma algebra we want is
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{A} 
&= \{\pi_J^{-1}(A), J\subset I \text{ countable}, A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{|J|})\}\\
&= \sigma( \pi_J^{-1}(A), J\subset I \text{ finite}, A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{|J|}))\\
&= \sigma( \pi_{\{x\}}^{-1}(A), x\in I, A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))
\end{aligned}
$$

Where the middle is ususally the definition because it meshes well with [Kolmogorov's extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem) which uses a consistent set of finite-dimensional marginal distributions.

If you view a sigma algebra as the set of questions you are allowed to ask, the sigma algebra $\mathcal{A}$ essentially allows you to ask questions about a countable set of points of your function. For general functions this does not allow you to separate a lot of functions. The set
$$
\{
  f\in \mathbb{R}^I : f\equiv c
\}
$$
is not measurable for example. But if we restrict ourselves to continuous functions, this set suddenly becomes measurable. Because we only need to know our function in the countable points in $D(I)$ for a separable $I$ due to continuity. More precisely, we have

$$
   \mathcal{A}|_{C(I)} = \mathcal{B}(C(I))\tag{*}
$$

where the topology of the Borel sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}(C(I))$ is generated by the metric

$$
   d(f,g) := \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\max\{d_k(f,g),1\}}{2^k},
   \quad d_k(f,g) := \sup_{x\in\overline{B_k(0)}}|f(x)-g(x)|
$$

where we assume that the ball  $\overline{B_k(0)}$ with radius $k$ is compact (need **Heine-Borel**).

###### Proof of (*):

###### $\subseteq$:

It is sufficient to prove that $\pi_{\{x\}}$ are continuous and therefore measurable, because $\mathcal{A}$ is the smallest sigma algebra to make them all measurable.

###### $\supseteq$:

Because the open balls around rational polynomials form a countable basis of the topology of $C(I)$ induced by $d$, it is sufficient to prove that the open balls are in $\mathcal{A}$. If we show that
$$
h_0: f\mapsto d(f_0, f)
$$
is measurable with regard to $\mathcal{A}$ we are done, because then
$$
B_\epsilon(f_0) = h_0^{-1}([0,\epsilon)) \in \mathcal{A}
$$

To prove $h_0$ is measurable it is sufficient to show that $h_k: f\mapsto d_k(f_0, f)$ is measurable.

But because

$$
h_k(f) = \sup_{x\in \overline{B_k(0)}\cap D(I)} |f(x)-f_0(x)|
= \sup_{x\in \overline{B_k(0)}\cap D(I)} |\pi_{\{x\}}(f)-\pi_{\{x\}}(f_0)|
$$

is just a countable supremum of measurable functions, it is measurable. Where we have used the separability of $I$ and the continuity of $f$ and $f_0$ when intersecting with the countable dense set $D(I)$.

##### Comparison with the Borel(Compact Open Topology)

The compact-open topology is defined as

$$
\tau( U_K(O):  K\subset I \text{ compact}, O\in \tau_{\mathbb{R}})
$$
where $\tau_{\mathbb{R}}$ are the open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ and we define
$$
U_K(O):= \{ f\in C(I) : f(K)\subset O\}
=\pi_K^{-1}(O\times\dots\times O).
$$
The second equality is not quite rigorous because for a compact $K$ we need the carthesian product of $|K|$ many $O$, which is generally uncountable.

For continuity of the evaluation function with regard to $d$ we only need to show, that the topology generated by $d$ is larger than the compact-open topology. For this, it is sufficient to show that every $U_K(O)$ is open with regards to $d$.

So let $U_K(O)$ be given. To show it is open, we need to find an epsilon ball around any element $f\in U_K(O)$, which we now assume as given. Using **Heine-Borel** again, there exists some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $K\subseteq \overline{B_k(0)}$

Then for $d(f,g)\le 2^{-k}$, we have
$$
   \sup_{x\in K} | f(x) - g(x)| \le d_k(f,g) \overset{d(f,g)\le 2^{-k}}\le 2^k d(f,g)
$$
So with an appropriate $\epsilon>0$ we can ensure by $d(f,g)\le\epsilon$ that
$$
\sup_{x\in K} | f(x) - g(x)|\le \eta. \tag{1}
$$
Let $\eta$ be the minimum distance of $f(y)$ and $O^\complement$. This is non-zero because $f(K)$ is compact and a subset of $O$.
So with (1), we can guarantee $g(K)\subset O$ for all $d(f,g)<\epsilon$. We have found our $\epsilon$ ball.

##### Comparison with Borel(Exponential Topology)

The borel sigma algebra of the exponential topology would have to be smaller than the one generated by all finite projections. Given that

> I am reasonably sure that the projections $\pi_J$ are measurable in the Borel-algebra, but I doubt that the Borel-algebra equals the cylinder algebra. I don't know for sure. To me, that is quite a weird thing to do, to take a product algebra for $I=\Bbb R^n$ (which is enormous!) - @FShrike

If the $\pi_J$ are measurable in the Borel-algebra, the smallest algebra to make them measurable $\mathcal{A}$ is going to be smaller or equal. If they are not equal, the measurability with regard to the Borel-algebra does not imply measurability with regard to $\mathcal{A}$.

Because I do not really understand the definition of the Exponential Topology well in the first place, I doubt that I will be able to make a more concrete statement in the near future.

Comment: +1 for sharing your thoughts. The result isn’t at all obvious and I’ll find you a reference soon!

Comment: @FShrike thank you! I will read it and then accept your answer once I understand it :)

Comment: @FShrike are the sets $U_K(O)=\{f \in \mathbb{R}^I: f(K)\subset O\}$ for compact $K$ and open $O$ in the exponential topology? (I am having trouble with your definition). If they are (similar to the compact-open top), then it might be possible to show that the borel sigma algebra will be larger. Because $U_{[0,1]}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{c\})^\complement=U_{[0,1]}(\{c\})=\{f: f|_{[0,1]}\equiv c\}$ would be in the sigma algebra. But it isn't in $\mathcal{A}$. Maybe there is a way to construct a counterexample for the evaluation function from this

Comment: Those sets $U_K(O)$ are the basic open sets for the standard compact-open topology, which is here the exponential topology. Not just similar to, but identical to, the compact-open topology. That is the topology suitable for $\Bbb R^I$ whenever $I$ is strongly locally compact

Comment: according to wikipedia, the compact-open topology is only defined on the set of continuous functions. Is that wrong?

Comment: Oh my. I had my head stuck in topology land. The compact-open topology can be given to all functions but it is only interesting if you consider continuous functions. I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: @FShrike so the exponential topology is not an extension of the compact-open topology? And does your answer not apply for non-continuous functions? Because then a lot of what is written above might be rubbish because I misunderstood what you claimed

Comment: The exponential topology is almost always taken to be the compact-open topology or some slightly modified version thereof. To my knowledge, C-O is the only construction we know of that is guaranteed to work (given suitable conditions). My answer does not apply for the set of arbitrary functions $I\to\Bbb R$, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

This post assumes $\Bbb R^I$ is taken with the compact-open topology, and is given the Borel sigma-algebra. $\Bbb R^I$ is used to denote the set of *continuous* functions $I\to\Bbb R$, so only addresses a special subcase of the problem.

---

[Reference](https://assets.pubpub.org/6d1dqgg9/51597355090422.pdf).

You mean the domain to be $\Bbb R^I\times I$, by the way.

The answer is *yes* since $I$ is locally compact Hausdorff in the sense that it is Hausdorff and there is a compact local base at every point. That means the evaluation is continuous, so in particular it is Borel measurable.

That is one condition for the exponential topology on $X^I$ (for any other space $X$) to exist. In fact, the compact-open topology on $V^U$ is exponential iff. the evaluation (‘call’): $$V^U\times U\overset{\rm{ev}}{\longrightarrow}V$$Is continuous.

By an ‘exponential topology’, I mean a topology on the set $V^U$ such that the adjunction pairing: $$f\mapsto\mathrm{ev}\circ(f\times1):W\times U\to V$$Among continuous $f:W\to V^U$ defines a bijection $C(W,V^U)\cong C(W\times U,V)$ for all spaces $W$. Under certain conditions, such as when one works in the category of compactly generated Hausdorff spaces, that last bijection is even a homeomorphism!

Note: the book I reference does dip a little into compactly generated Hausdorff spaces, but it doesn’t do so very well or in great detail / rigour. Also, be warned that conflicting definitions of ‘compactly generated’ can cause serious problems! There is a paper by Strickland, if I remember correctly, that covers compactly generated spaces and their nice categorical properties in good detail.

Comment: oh dear, I am new to category theory, so this is going to be a ride

Comment: @FelixB. yeah, that book has a categorical swing to it. You can ignore most of it though! It's just words at that level. I'll try to find the relevant pages, which are purely topology

Comment: @FelixB. Page 106, theorem 5.6 is the main bit.

Comment: Can you always construct a topology on $\mathbb{R}^I$, and if so, does the borel sigma algebra generated by it always coincide with the sigma algebra generated by all finite dimensional cylinders? I.e. the smallest sigma algebra such that all projections into finite dimensional space are measurable. (I know that the borel sigma algebra coincides with the sigma algebra of finite dim cylinders for continuous functions.)

Comment: @FelixB. What do you mean by a projection from $(\Bbb R)^{\Bbb R^n}$ into finite dimensional space?

Comment: Let $\{t_1,\dots,t_n\}=J\subset I$ be a finite subset. Then $\pi_J(f) = (f(t_1),\dots, f(t_n))$ is a projection of $f\in\mathbb{R}^I$ into a finite dimensional space. And $\pi_J^{-1}(A)$ for $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a cylinder. The usual sigma algebra defined on $\mathbb{R}^I$ is $\sigma( \pi_J^{-1}(A) : J\subset I\text{ finite}, A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{|J|}))$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140934/discussion-between-fshrike-and-felix-b).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2337876/is-the-evaluation-map-yi-times-i-to-y-continuous-for-general-y

Comment: @FelixB. That's about continuity, which I've talked about in my answer.

Comment: yes - since this approach is basically using continuity to deduce measurability. So the question in this case essentially becomes: is the evaluation function continuous. Which is why this question is related, correct? I just wanted it to show up in the linked questions

Comment: We already know the evaluation is continuous :) @FelixB. The trouble is, is the algebra the one you want? I don't know